# tapgesturerecognizer not working in flutter webview

Tags: flutter, dart

I tried using GestureRecognizer in flutter webview to zoom out on Double pinch.But it is not working. If you have any solution then please help me

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';

void main()=>runApp(WebView());

class WebView extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _WebViewState createState() => _WebViewState();
}

class _WebViewState extends State<WebView> {
  final Completer<WebViewController> _controller =
      Completer<WebViewController>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(


      body: Builder(builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return WebView(
          key: UniqueKey(),
          gestureRecognizers:
          Set()..add(Factory<TapGestureRecognizer>(() => TapGestureRecognizer(),)),//ZOOM WEBVIEW

          initialUrl:
              'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/',

          javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
          onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
            _controller.complete(webViewController);
          },
        );
      }),

    );
  }
}
```

This was the important part of code If you need full code then please comment.

Answer (score 8):

I run at the same problem and was able to make `TapGestureRecognizer` work by wrapping `WebView` into `GestureDetector` with `onTap()` inside of it. Except that I don't know why does it work.

```
@override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  body: GestureDetector(
    onTap: () {
      print("This one doesn't print");
    },
    child: Container(
      child: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          WebView(
            initialUrl:
                'example.com',
            javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
            onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
              _controller.complete(webViewController);
            },
            gestureRecognizers: Set()
              ..add(
                  Factory<TapGestureRecognizer>(() => TapGestureRecognizer()
                    ..onTapDown = (tap) {
                      print("This one prints");
                    })),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
}
```

Wondering if anyone had similar issue and made it work properly.

Comment: Maybe this is the right way to work with webviews but there is one another issue, onTapDown is working fine but onTap is not working, do you have any idea about it?

Answer (score 1):

Until there is not a proper way to do it, I have done it like below for my case

```
Container(
    child: Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        WebView(
          initialUrl:
              'example.com',
          javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
          onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
            _controller.complete(webViewController);
          },
          gestureRecognizers: Set()
            ..add(
                Factory<TapGestureRecognizer>(() => TapGestureRecognizer()
                  ..onTapDown = (tap) {
                    print("This one prints");
                  })),
        ),
        GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                print("ontap");
              },
              child: Container(
                  color: Colors.transparent,
                  width: double.infinity,
                  height: 50,
              ),
            )
      ],
    ),
  ),
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem on iOS, simply add the following line of code to your info.plist file.

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
 <dict>
 <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key><true/>
</dict>
```

Hope this solves the problem for you.